# Have child span the full height of a growing flex item

Tags: css, flexbox, safari

**EDIT: This may be a problem with Safari 14.0.x for macOS.**

I’m trying to make the `.block` element in the middle `.flex-item` span the full height of its parent, but it instead just collapses.

```css
body {
    height: calc(100vh - 2 * 4px);
    margin: 4px;
}

div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-width: 0.8vh;
    border-style: solid;
    padding: 2vh;
}

.flex {
    height: 100%;
    border-color: red;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-item {
    border-color: blue;
}

.box {
    height: 15vh;
    border-color: green;
    padding: 0;
}

.flex-item:last-child > .box {
    height: 8vh;
}

.grow {
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.grow > .box {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
    <div class="flex-item">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item grow">
        <div class="box two"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I could edit the last of the code to what’s below to make it work, but I’d rather not have one child be displayed as `flex` while the others are displayed as `block`. Is there another way I could go about doing this?

```
.grow {
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.grow > .box {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```css
body {
    height: calc(100vh - 2 * 4px);
    margin: 4px;
}

div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-width: 0.8vh;
    border-style: solid;
    padding: 2vh;
}

.flex {
    height: 100%;
    border-color: red;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.flex-item {
    border-color: blue;
}

.box {
    height: 15vh;
    border-color: green;
    padding: 0;
}

.flex-item:last-child > .box {
    height: 8vh;
}

.grow {
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.grow > .box {
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
    <div class="flex-item">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item grow">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The code you posted already does what you say you're trying to make it do.

Comment: @ksav For some reason on Safari 14.0.2 (16610.3.7.1.9) for macOS, it doesn’t display right: the height of the middle `.box` collapses. On Safari 14.1 for iOS, it looks fine. I will try updating my computer.

Comment: @ksav It doesn’t work with Safari 14.0.3 (16610.4.3.1.7) on macOS either.

Comment: Works as expected on 14.0.1 (15610.2.11.51.10, 15610), macOS Catalina 10.15.7.

Comment: @0stone0 I wonder if it’s an issue with macOS Big Sur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set it as follow:

```
.grow {
    flex-grow: 1;
    height: 100%;
}

.grow > .box {
    height: 100%;
}
```

This does seem to the trick for me in Safari.
If you don't want to use flexbox on the `.grow` element.

Comment: Not what you were looking for?